# NetworkX: Node labels are drawn randomly

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

So I wanted to draw labels for each of my node (1-20), but somehow these labels are just drawn randomly on the graph (check screen below).

```
network = nx.DiGraph()
counter = 0
for i in range(1,21):
    network.add_node(i, label = str(i))
with open('mreza.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        for item in row:
            item = item.strip('(').strip(')').split(',')
            startVertex = int(item[0])
            endVertex = int(item[1])
            network.add_weighted_edges_from([(startVertex, endVertex, matchingArray[counter])])
            counter = counter + 1
pos=nx.spring_layout(network)
nx.draw(network)
labels = nx.draw_networkx_labels(network,pos,font_size=10)
plt.show()
```

[nan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLjPG.png)

Comment: To better answer your question, let me ask this first: any reason why you create nodes first and then edges?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know really. Well, how am I supposed to create edges between non-existent nodes? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The nodes will be automatically created for you, no need to create them in a separate loop - that's one of the reasons behind your problems. I will try to answer your original question. If it's going to be precisely your solution depends much on what was your intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code:

- You create nodes and edges separately. The labels that you think are random are associated with nodes that you have created in the first loop (I guess).
- `draw` can be called with extra argument to draw labels, i.e. `nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, font_size=10)`.
- `add_weighted_edges_from` is supposed to be given a container of edges. You're sort of abusing this function to add edges. If you insist on going with a loop, consider using [add_edge](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_edge.html#networkx.DiGraph.add_edge).

Considering that you load your data from csv, I'd not go into loops at all. Instead, I'd load my data into `pandas` dataframe and then use [from_pandas_edgelist](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html#networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist) like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.read_csv('mreza.csv')
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, pos, 'pos')
```

Mind that your `df` needs to have two mandatory columns: `source` and `target`. Pre-process your `df` if necessary. Add `weight` and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and detail reply. I did not use your pandas package, but I fixed other issues you mentioned and everything is working just fine now! Looks like `nx.set_node_attributes` did the thing for me. Thank you again :)

Comment: @doksara I am glad to hear it worked! Now, if you could accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers